# Spring - Advanced comparator for QueryDsl support

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

Following the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe), adding `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` annotation to my Spring configuration allows to automatically inject a `Predicate` class in query:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path="/find")
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<FooResource>> find(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<Foo> assembler, @QuerydslPredicate(root = Foo.class) Predicate predicate) {
    Page<Foo> foos = fooRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable)
    final ResourceAssemblerSupport<Foo, FooResource> fooResourceAssembler = new ....;
    final PagedResources<FooResource> pagedResources = assembler.toResource(foos, fooResourceAssembler);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(pagedResources, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Then I can easily search when performing the GET request:

```
GET /foo/name?=bob&name=alice&age=20
```

This works fine. However I was wondering how to achieve more advanced search criteria:

- `>`
- `<`
- `>=`
- `<=`

Typically I would like to apply these operators to numeric and date fields in my data models. These sorts of criterion are supported in Querydsl.

I tried adding `> (%3E)` in my query parameters but it fails parsing (for example for numeric field like age it complains it cannot parse `>10` as a number.

Is it possible to use this operator directly in the query?

(In case it matters I'm using Spring Data Mongodb)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to implement this?  I have been trying to implement something similar, but with no success.

Comment: @woemler I have actually parked that issue for now but it's not going away. I think I will end up writing my own code to parse de query parameters. I need to check if there is an easy way to integrate it with the spring injection mechanism. When I get to do that I will probably ask for advice on the spring github repository. Will write it here as an answer if I find something interesting

Comment: @phoenix7360 anything come up? I'm also looking to do this but still use `@QuerydslPredicate`

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica unfortunately I never managed to achieve this and just gave up :/

Comment: @phoenix7360 
Spring Data Querydsl Value Operators library does this...

Answer (score 4):

**Custom Query DSL binding - greater than comparison**

What you can do is define your own QueryDSL Binding in your repository, by extending `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` and `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`:

```
public interface FooRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Foo, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Foo>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QFoo> {

    default void customize(final QuerydslBindings bindings, final QFoo foo) {
        SingleValueBinding<NumberPath<Integer>, Integer> singleBinding = new SingleValueBinding<NumberPath<Integer>,Integer>(){
            @Override
            public Predicate bind(NumberPath<Integer> path, Integer ageValue) {
                return path.gt(ageValue);
            }
        };

        bindings.bind(foo.age).first(singleBinding);
    }
}
```

I'm no Query DSL expert, but my understanding is the following:

> a binding defines how a specific field is to be compared to its
>   database column.

The same binding with java 8 lambda: `(path, ageValue) -> path.gt(ageValue)`. You have to read the code in customize method from the url parameter's perspective:

> fetch the Foos for which the age provided as parameter is greater than
>   the database's value.

**Custom Query DSL binding - between comparison**

Another option is to provide lower and upper bound for your parameter, like this: `?age=10&age=30`. Then, define the following binding:

```
default void customize(final QuerydslBindings bindings, final QFoo foo) {
    bindings.bind(foo.age).all((path, values) -> {
        Iterator<? extends Long> it = values.iterator();
        return path.between(it.next(), it.next());
    });
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. The only problem is that this doesn't allow to customise the actual parsing of the expression. Because of the way the datatypes are set, it's not possible to have a int field but parse a String (for example containing ">"). this seems to be a limitation of spring.

Comment: @alexbt hey your tip was very useful to me. But in my case I would need make a age filter for gt, eq and lt. I tried to give different aliases for the age attribute using their respective singleBinding (gt, eq, lt). But it seems one attribute can't have more than one alias. Do you know how could I use gt, eq and lt for the same attribute? Thanks.